# SSRS With A Disclaimer Page

Tags: reporting-services

I need a solution that will do the following.
When a report is run, it follows up with a disclaimer page.
However, if the report data runs over two pages, I need the disclaimer after each page.  So, if the report is one page, page 1 is the report data and page 2 is the disclaimer.  If the report spans over two pages, page 1 is the first portion of the report, page 2 is disclaimer, page 3 is second portion of the report, page 4 is disclaimer.

Comment: which export format are you using?

Answer (score -1):

I cant think of a general method in ssrs to achieve that,
(depending on the structure of your report, there might be some tricks for example with groupings by lines of text, and a footer of the size of a page, that repeats every group, but that is assuming a text line is also a row in your dataset, which in turn is assuming you can manipulate your dataset with stored procedure. tl;dr; it depends and gets complicated quickly)

however, assuming you use c# to render your reports, using pdfsharp you could
prepare the disclaimer as pdf and simply add it after everey page in "post processing"
(something like that)

```
var document PdfReader.Open(StreamForPDf, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import)
var disclaimer PdfReader.Open(pathorStream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import)
var result = new PdfDocument();
foreach (var page in document.pages)
{
    result.add(page);
    result.add(diclaimer.pages[0]);
}
result.save(streamorpath);
```